# Is it possible to get  two Viewgroup in single xml?then how?

Tags: android

parent as relative layout i have textview (for title) and linearlayout for viewgroup in that by id am accessing viewgroup. and inside child linear layout i have textview and relative layout for image and textview .after viewgroup in my above linear layout i want to access one  viewgroup how to do that?

Comment: please modify your question . It is not understandable.

Comment: view_example_group_id is for  view group ,single_verb_meaning_text_id this is title for this viewgroup...after this i like to add title and one mre viewgroup if i create linearlayout under this its throwing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not understand what do you want to achieve, but you must remember, that layout structure in Android is a tree. Every two View Groups can have a parent View Group above them. So just instantiate a root layout and then place any number of View Groups you need there. Good luck!

Comment: i am trying to get two view group in single xml file.

Comment: view_example_group_id is for  view group ,single_verb_meaning_text_id this is title for this viewgroup...after this i like to add title and one mre viewgroup if i create linearlayout under this its throwing error

Comment: So you must also create one above and put these two inside it. Is it clear?

Comment: yes i created one textview(title)and linearlayout(viewgroup) above this, its showing error symbol in xml

Comment: Where are the starting tags? You can't specify a TextView as a root view of your layout.

Comment: could  u pls tell what modification i need to do?

Comment: Please read this post carefully and I'm sure you'll resolve your problem. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
Good luck!